# How to pass generic type as parameter to Enum.Parse()

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have a class with a generic method:

```
public record OperationCollectionGeneric<OPERATIONTYPE> where OPERATIONTYPE: notnull, Enum
{
    public OPERATIONTYPE Group { get; }

    public OperationCollectionGeneric(string part1, string? part2 = null, string? part3 = null)
    {
        Group = Enum.Parse<OPERATIONTYPE>(part1, true);
    }
```

The `Enum.Parse()` method has the following error:

> Error CS0453  The type 'OPERATIONTYPE' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'TEnum' in the generic type or method 'Enum.Parse(ReadOnlySpan, bool)'

How can I pass the make sure that OPERATIONTYPE parameter is of type Enum

I tried to use the `where` keywork to set the enum type for the `OPERATIONTYPE` but it does not work.

Comment: You need `where OPERATIONTYPE: struct, Enum`. The constraint you have lets someone do `OperationCollectionGeneric<Enum>`, where you literally pass the `Enum` type

Comment: _"must be a non-nullable **value type**"_. You probably fixated on the "not-nullable" bit, but the important part was "value type"; `struct` defines a value type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Enum.Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.parse?view=net-7.0#system-enum-parse-1(system-readonlyspan((system-char)))) is restricted to `struct`'s, so change generic constraints to match it:

```cs
public record OperationCollectionGeneric<OPERATIONTYPE> where OPERATIONTYPE : struct, Enum
```

Answer (score -1):

OPERATIONTYPE must be a non-nullable value type, but `System.Enum` is a reference type.

Comment: `System.Enum` is a very special type which inherits from another very special type `System.ValueType` - base class for every value type.